# How do I convert a Hex color to VBA color to use in Powerpoint in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, hex

I need to create a function in T-SQL that will take a Hex color and convert it into a color number to use in VBA for Powerpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct answer: B*65536 + G*256 + R